# Google Maps overlay not showing

Tags: javascript, google-maps, overlay

I have a google map with kmz overlay on my site:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
<!--
    var geocoder;
    var map;
    var overlayXml;

    function initialize() {
//      if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(25,-24);
        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 2,
            center: latlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

//        map.setUIToDefault();

        var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer('http://linktothe/data.kmz');
        ctaLayer.setMap(map);
//      }
    }

    function codeAddress() {
        var address = document.getElementById("address").value;
        geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                map.setZoom(10);     
            } else {
                alert("Could not navigate to location. Reason: " + status);
            }
        });
    }

//-->
</script> 

</head> 
<body onload="initialize()" onunload="GUnload()"> 
etc.
```

There are two problems:

1) When I first go to the page, the overlay is not showing. I have to refresh the page for it to show. I have no idea why that happens. Maybe it's because the overlay is very big (about 3500 markers)? I believe I have already exhausted my options (the file used to be >1MB before I switched to the compressed kmz version).

2) Once I get the overlay to load, it has an unwanted behavior. The map is zoomed out from its initial position to show the whole overlay. How can I control this behavior?

Comment: Can you post the HTML? It would be nice to be able to reproduce your problem in jsfiddle.

Comment: Lot of possibilities. Does the kml works in GEarth? Any special projection used in GMaps?. What is in the KML? Points, polyline, shapes? Disable the geocoder part, try loading from local, any <Tour, AbastractView> tags?